# Create onlineMeeting Fails with 403 Forbidden following Microsoft instructions for Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman, bearer-token

Attempting to create an online meeting via Postman following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

I have signed up for a free developer account at [Microsoft Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).  I have successfully created an additional user.  I have successfully registered a test application:
[image: Azure Registered Application]

I have created Bearer tokens with scope User.Read.All, OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite, Calendars.ReadWrite using both the TenantID ( login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize ) and the organizations path ( login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize ) patterns,
[image: Postman Configure New Token], and have verified the API permissions in Azure. [image]

I have set up my Microsoft Graph environment for Postman (I believe) correctly, setting ClientID, ClientSecret, TenantID, UserPassword, and UserName. [image: MS Graph environment]

I have been able to connect via Postman and query both users (Get Users) and my user profile (Get My Profile), and have successfully received responses for both.

I believe I have configured my POST headers correctly. [image: POST Headers]

I am posting the following JSON content:

```
{
"startDateTime": "2021-01-22T14:30:34.2444915-05:00",
"endDateTime": "2021-01-22T15:00:34.2464912-05:00",
"subject": "User Token Meeting"
}
```

The problem here is that regardless of Token used (either the generated {{UserAccessToken}} when using {{TenantID}} or copy/pasting the token from the ../organizations/.. pattern), and whether I post to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings  or https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings, I am receiving a 403 Forbidden Status response.
[image: Status 403 Forbidden]

I'm honestly not sure if this is due to something I have done wrong or if there is a problem with Azure "free" developer accounts not having the rights to create meetings.
[image: Status 403 with response headers]

Does anybody have a solution for this?  Or a link to instructions on creating a Teams meeting via Postman that **works**?

Thanks.

Comment: How old is your token? The default lifetime for an access token seems to be 1 hour.

Comment: When my token expires I get a Token-expired response.  When I request a new token and then try to create the meeting I receive the 403 Forbidden response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must **LOG INTO TEAMS AT LEAST ONCE** before creating meetings via API.

Please refer to @Joy Wang's answer regarding Licenses, as I believe that was also necessary.

Once I set my licenses correctly I still could not get it to work until after I logged into Teams using the test Developer credentials.  I had never logged in before, just went directly to API work.  After I did the initial login the API calls from Postman began to return a 201 - Created response.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue with an `Azure AD Free` tenant, I suppose you also use that.

[image]

And it works in an `Azure AD Premium P2` tenant.

[image]

Looks the issue should be related to the [Azure AD Pricing tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)(maybe related to the Microsoft Teams License more specific, not an expert about that, not say much here), so to solve this issue, you could upgrade your Azure AD License, if you have not used the Free trial before, you could navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` -> `Licenses`, active the `Premium P2` to have a try.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Joy Wang for your response.  I followed your instructions, and then (additionally):

1) Assigned the license to a user
2) Requested (and received) new access token
3) Verified the token works by GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users (and receiving a valid response) 
4) Tested meeting creation by POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings.  

Unfortunately I'm still getting the 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Hi, I am using a test account created specifically for prototyping the creation of MS Teams Meeting via API.  My work account access is controlled via corporate administration, and I don't want to use that account (as it is "real").  So I am using a free azure development account for this.  

I have added the additional permission "TeamsApp.ReadWrite" as a granted permission, and still failing with the 403 Forbidden response.  I'm at a bit of a loss, as everything else seems to work just fine.  I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I am an idiot.  The userid I was using had never logged into teams.  Thanks for your help, I suspect the license issue was necessary as well.  For those reading this and having the same problem, you need to LOG INTO TEAMS AT LEAST ONCE before trying to create meetings via api.   (shaking head feeling stupid)